# Do I need to replace this toilet ring?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, replacement

You can see the ring is broken on the right side.

[image: Toilet Ring]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - the rectangular hole on the right leads to a curved slot that holds the bolts used to secure your toilet.  Your slot is broken which means the right side of the toilet will not be secure.  This could (read will) lead to a rocking toilet (not in a good way) which will be followed by leaks (um, eww) and rotted subfloors or worse.

A [repair flange like this](http://www.lowes.com/ProductDisplay?partNumber=23443-138-436483) will work, but a [full ring like this](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Sioux-Chief-Stainless-Steel-Flange-Repair-Ring-886-MR/202274075) is better.

And I'd lean toward a stainless repair kit so there is less worry in the future.

Comment: Could I just cut it all out and put in a new one.

Comment: @Ben You sir speak like a true toilet scientist. Vote up!

Comment: yes, especially if you have access to the bottom side via basement or crawl space.  Otherwise, a inside pipe cutter tool (like this http://m.homedepot.com/p/HDX-Internal-Diameter-PVC-Pipe-Cutter-67516/204277491) is needed and it is a bit more complicated to ensure it is the right height for the subfloor and drain slope.  Not worth the hassle in my book.

Comment: I have plenty of access the toilet is upstairs and the downstairs ceiling is open. Might try the easy way first though.

Comment: If you have access, then look into a full replacement with a stainless steel ring.  Shouldn't be too hard at all.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, yes. Look for "toilet flange repair" kits on your favorite search engine or at your favorite big box / plumbing store. Many of them are fairly low profile, but you'll need to be sure you don't end up too high.